Failed to resolve: androidx.activiy:activity-ktx:1.9.0
I am receivig this error when syncing my gradle files:

Failed to resolve: androidx.activiy:activity-ktx:1.9.0

My build.gradle.kts (module) is:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
}

My build.gradle.kts (app) is:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    namespace = "es.proyectoFinalFP.agendaescolar"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "es.proyectoFinalFP.agendaescolar"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        //configuracion de exportacion para room
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                //arguments += ["room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
                arguments.putAll(mapOf("room.schemaLocation" to "$projectDir/schemas".toString()))
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    val room_version = "2.6.1"
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    implementation (libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation (libs.material)
    implementation (libs.activity.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.activity.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.room.runtime)
    kapt (libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)

}

And my libs.versions.toml is
[versions]
activityKtx = "1.9.0"
agp = "8.6.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.6"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.2"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
roomRuntime = "2.6.1"

[libraries]
activity-ktx = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-ktx", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-activity-ktx = { module = "androidx.activiy:activity-ktx", version.ref = "activityKtx" }
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrainsKotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

and finally, my settings.gradle.kts is
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "AgendaEscolar"
include(":app")


Please share detailed error messages.

Could not find androidx.activiy:activity-ktx:1.9.0.
Required by:
project :app
Search in build.gradle files

Failed to resolve: androidx.activiy:activity-ktx:1.9.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

This is probably due to a version incompatibility. Did you update the Gradle version or make any changes? If so, I suggest reverting the changes and trying again.
Moreover, you can try updating the androidx.core dependencies.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core

In your version catalog you have this line in the [libraries] block:
androidx-activity-ktx = { module = "androidx.activiy:activity-ktx", version.ref = "activityKtx" }

This has a typo in activiy, there is a t missing. You do not even need this line, though, because the line above already has this with the proper spelling, so just remove the erroneous line and you should be fine.
Just remember to also remove the according line in your app-level gradle file:
implementation (libs.androidx.activity.ktx)

